# Why is there a list index out range error on leetcode?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
def rob(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    nums[len(nums) - 3] = nums[len(nums) - 3] + nums[len(nums)-1]
    for i in range(len(nums) - 4, -1, -1):
        print(nums[i])
        nums[i] += max(nums[i+2], nums[i+3])
    return max(nums[0], nums[1])
```

On repl there was no Error, but on Leetcode says there was, can anyone help me?
link for the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/

Comment: List of zero length?

Comment: The task has constraints: `1 <= nums.length <= 100`. You use indexes for `nums`, such as `len(nums) - 3` and `len(nums) - 4`, which, for example, for nums.length==1 are evaluated as -2 and -3 , so the error occurs